# What are these foil covered copper shingles called? What can I learn about them?

Tags: roofing, copper, shingles

I'm looking for anything on this style of shingle

[image: Copper covered foil shingles]

I need to help replace a few of these, and so far have not found anything in terms of vendor, date, supply, or even a name.  Other than "copper covered foil asphalt shingles" what might they be called?

Comment: Usually roofers stay local.  I would ask around the local roofers to find out.  Good chance one of them put the shingles on or know of them.

Comment: Well that's a new one to me. I've seen (pictures  of) copper roofing as small rectangles with folded seams, (supposed to be a Japanese traditional method) but this product is downright odd.